# Android : Set background color for listfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I m creating the elements of listfragment using newView and bindView. The list gets constructed fine. Each row of the list has a separator.

[image]

I guess the color between these separators is getting picked by default android theme. I tried setting this color to white using this code in onCreateView().

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

But it complains that content view is not yet created.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Fragment will not have its content View until `onCreateView(`) is called...
so `getListView()` in `onCreateView()` returns `null` and move the code in `onCreateView()` to `onViewCreated()`...

usually you don't need to override `onCrateView()` method in `ListFragment` as it overrides for you and instantiates `ListView` as its content

and below code assumes that you are extending `ListFragment`...

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
        listView.setDividerHeight(3); // 3 pixels height
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a style. Something like in your **res/values/styles.xml**:

```
<!-- ListViews -->
<style name="ListViews" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#0000</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/list_divider</item>
    <!--
        Despite the warning about using pixels, this is actually the correct
        way do the trick. Otherwise, the divider would be scaled.
    -->
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
</style>
```

having **res/drawable/list_divider.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

If you extended Fragment, in your layout, in your ListView definition:

```
style="@style/ListViews"
```

Comment: I m just defining how each row of the list will look. I dont have a layout with <Listview>

Comment: Sorry. I assumed you did like me and extended Fragment instead of ListFragment (so I can assign a custom Layout, where I define a ListView)

Comment: newView and bindView are helpful for lazy loading list items , pretty good.